# Forwarding journald to Cloudwatch Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, centos, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm a newbie to CentOS and wanted to know the best way to parse journal logs to CloudWatch Logs.

My thought processes so far are:

- Use FIFO to parse the journal logs and ingest this to Cloudwatch Logs,  - It looks like this could come with draw backs where logs could be dropped if we hit buffering limits.
- Forward journal logs to syslog and send syslogs to Cloudwatch Logs --

The idea is essentially to have everything logging to journald as JSON and then forward this across to CloudWatch Logs.

What is the best way to do this? How have others solved this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/saymedia/journald-cloudwatch-logs by Matin Atkins.

This open source project creates a binary that does exactly what you want - ship your (systemd) journald logs to AWS CloudWatch Logs.

The project depends on `libsystemd` to forward directly to CloudWatch.  It does not rely on forwarding to syslog.  This is a good thing.

The project appears to use golang's concurrent channels to read the logs and batches writes.

Comment: Excellent this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at https://github.com/advantageous/systemd-cloud-watch

We had problems with **journald-cloudwatch-logs**. It just did not work for us at all.

It does not limit the size of the message or commandLine that it sends to CloudWatch and the CloudWatch sends back an error that journald-cloudwatch-logs cannot handle which makes it out of sync.

**systemd-cloud-watch** is stateless and it asks CloudWatch where it left off.

**systemd-cloud-watch** also creates the log-group if missing.

**systemd-cloud-watch** also uses the name tag and the private ip address so that you can easily find the log you are looking for.

We also include a packer file to show you how to build and configure a systemd-cloud-watch image with EC2/Centos/Systemd. There is no question about how to configure systemd because we have a working example.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the headsup on this, looks exactly like what we want. I'm really new to Go so just wondering how i get this installed?

I've followed the steps here - http://www.mammatustech.com/cloud-news/settingup-aws-log-agent-journald-dcos-logs-to-amazon-cloudwatch-log-service

But when I get to "Install agent software" I download the github rep, but the steps from there on down match up. It seems like the curl command downloads a binary, but not exactly sure what to do with it.

Thanks

Comment: I think its worth noting that systemd-cloud-watch forked and largely rewrote journald-cloudwatch-logs (See licence section of the readme).

Answer (score 6):

[Vector](https://vector.dev) can be used to ship logs from journald to AWS CloudWatch Logs.

[journald](https://vector.dev/docs/reference/sources/journald/) can be used as a source and [AWS Cloudwatch Logs](https://vector.dev/docs/reference/sinks/aws_cloudwatch_logs/) as a sink.

I'm working on integrating this with an existing deployment of about 6 EC2 instances that generate about 30 GB of logs daily.  I'll update this answer with any caveats or gotchas after we've used Vector in production for a few weeks.

EDIT 8/17/2020

A few things to be aware of.  The match batch size for the PutLogEvents is 1MB and there is a max of 5 requests per second per stream.  [See the limits here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch_limits_cwl.html).

To help with that, in my set up each journald unit has it's own log stream.   Also, there are a lot of fields that the Vector journald sink includes, I used a vector transform to remove all the ones I didn't need.  However, I'm still running into rate limits.

EDIT 10/6/2020

I have this running in production now.  I had to update the version of vector I was using from 0.8.1 to 0.10.0 to take care an issue with vector not respecting the max bytes per batch requirement for AWS CloudWatch logs.  As far as the rate limit issues I was experiencing, it turns out I wasn't having any issues.  I was getting this message in the vector logs `tower_limit::rate::service: rate limit exceeded, disabling service`.  What that actually means is that vector is pausing send logs temporarily to respect the rate limit of the sink. Also, each Cloudwatch Log Stream can consume up to 18 GB per hour which is fine for my 30 GB per day requirement for over 30 different services on 6 VMs.

One issue I did run into was causing the CPU to spike on our main API service.  I had a source for each service unit to tail the journald logs.  I believe this somehow blocked our API from not being able to write to journald (not 100% though).  What I did was have one source and specified multiple units to follow so there was only one command tailing the logs and I increased the batch size since each service generates a lot of logs.  I then used vector's template syntax to split the Log Group and Log Stream based on the service name.  Below is an example configuration:

```
[sources.journald_logs]
  type = "journald"
  units = ["api", "sshd", "vector", "review", "other-service"]
  batch_size = 100

[sinks.cloud_watch_logs]
  type = "aws_cloudwatch_logs"
  inputs = ["journald_logs"]
  group_name = "/production/{{host}}/{{_SYSTEMD_UNIT}}"
  healthcheck = true
  region = "${region}"
  stream_name = "{{_SYSTEMD_UNIT}}"
  encoding = "json"
```

I have one final issue I need to iron out, but it's not related to this question.  I'm using a file source for nginx since it writes to an access log file.  Vector is consuming 80% of the CPU on that machine getting the logs and sending them to AWS CloudWatch.  Filebeat also runs on the same box sending the logs to Logstash, but it's never caused any issues.  Once we get vector working reliably we'll retire the Elastic Stack, but for now we have them running side by side.

Comment: Hello Covertlll, how is it going so far? Any caveats or gotchas?

Comment: @PedroNeri I ran into the CloudWatch logs rate limit by sending the logs directly to CloudWatch.  I'm still working through the issue.  I'll update this answer when I find a solution.  I'm going to try to update the config to increase the buffer.  If that doesn't work, I may use AWS Kinesis Firehose or Kafka as a queue for the logs.

Comment: Using journald as a Vector source: https://vector.dev/docs/reference/sources/journald/. Using AWS CloudWatch as a Vector log sink: https://vector.dev/docs/reference/sinks/aws_cloudwatch_logs/